# Почему не работают некоторый SQL команды?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Вот мой код:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tsecret1_users;';
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'tsecret1_Sys', 'i$Q5****.2m.');

//Переменные
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];
  $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];
  $pass2_hash = hash("sha256", $pass2);
  $session = hash("sha512", $email);
  $email_base64 = base64_encode($email);

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `Exiting Users` WHERE email = ?';
  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute([$email]);
  $row = $sql->fetchAll;

  $num_rows = count($row);
  echo $num_rows;
  if ($num_rows == 0) {
    if ($pass == $pass2) {
      //Регистрация
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `Exiting Users`(`email`) VALUES (:email)';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["email" => $email]);

      $sql = 'CREATE TABLE `tsecret1_users`.`:email` ( `PassWord` TEXT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MyISAM';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["email" => $email]);

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `:email`(`PassWord`) VALUES (:pass2_hash)';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["email" => $email, "pass2_hash" => $pass2_hash]);

      $sql = 'ALTER TABLE `:email` ADD `parameters` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `PassWord`';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["email" => $email]);

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `?`(`parameters`) VALUES (`EmailIsNotVerified`)';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute([$email]);

      //Открытие сессии
      $sql = 'ALTER TABLE `:email` ADD `Sessions` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `parameters`';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["email" => $email]);

      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `:email`(`Sessions`) VALUES (`:session`)';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["session" => $session]);
    }
  }
?>
```

Проблема:
Не работают команды:
`` $sql = 'INSERT INTO `:email`(`Sessions`) VALUES (`:session`)'; ``

И
`` $sql = 'INSERT INTO `?`(`parameters`) VALUES (`EmailIsNotVerified`)'; ``

Спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('column value');` - сравните запрос со своим и попытайтесь найти ошибку.

Comment: Я не смог найти ошибку...

Comment: Кажись, понятно... Вы что для каждого юзера базу создаёте? `CREATE TABLE `tsecret1_users`.`:email` ( `PassWord` TEXT NOT NULL ) ...` что это вообще такое? `Exiting Users` - это название таблицы?..

Comment: Не базу, а таблицу. И да, таблица называется  `Exiting Users `

Comment: Киньте скрин. Что за наркомания)

Comment: Скрин чего - Кода или Базы?

Comment: Базы скрин, желаельно

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/B8BDV1Y.png

Comment: А зачем вы так делаете? Это не корректно, мягко говоря

Answer (score 0):

Эмм..
У вас запрос не корректно составлен.
Что говорит отладка запроса?

`print_r($query->errorInfo());`

```
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO `:email`(`Sessions`) VALUES (`:session`)';
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["session" => $session]);
```

у вас в запросе две переменных. `email`, `session`
а в параметры передаете одно значение. `session`

Comment: Привет, поставил `print_r($query->errorInfo());`, Вот итог: `Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: Ну по коду ошибки он вам это и сказал. 
Не верное количество параметров.

Comment: Теперь код такой: `$sql = "INSERT INTO `:email` (`Sessions`) VALUES (':session')";
      $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(["email" => $email, "session" => $session]);
      print_r($query->errorInfo());`, Ошибка таже...